# How to remove one specific factor level in all factor variables in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, na

For example, I have data frame with 6 columns (all are factors).

I want to delete a specific level, for example "no", from all factors, in which this level appears.

I want to drop the factor level "no" from my factor variable and at the same time I want to delete (set to NA's) all answers, that have "no" value.

I have tried this code:

```
sapply(fact,function(x) levels(x)[levels(x) == "no"] <- NULL)
```

But this code doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: This isn’t a direct answer but consider whether `droplevels` is appropriate in your case. If it is, your code simplifies to `lapply(fact, droplevels)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, in such a case, they could just use `droplevels(fact)`

Comment: As Konrad noted, your question is not clear. Do you want to drop observations with "no" as the answer, or have they been dropped and you simply want to remove this level from the factor levels?

Comment: @lmo  I want to drop the factor level "no" form my factor variable and at the same time I want to delete(set to NA's) all answers, that have "no" value.

Comment: To convert a factor across all cols to NA use `lapply(df, function(x) { levels(x)[levels(x) %in% 'c']=NA ; return(x) })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
dfNew <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {is.na(x[x=="no"]) <- TRUE; droplevels(x)}))
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(q1=sample(c("yes", "no", "maybe"), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 q2=sample(c("yes", "no", "maybe"), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 q3=sample(c("yes", "no", "maybe"), 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
> df
   # c1  c2  c3
# 1 yes yes  no
# 2  no  ok yes
# 3  ok  no  ok
# 4 yes yes  no
# 5  no  ok yes
# 6  ok  no  ok
# 7 yes yes  no
# 8  no  ok yes
# 9  ok  no  ok

toRemove <- "no"
data.frame(lapply(df, 
          function(x) factor(as.character(x), levels=levels(x)[levels(x)!=toRemove])))

    # c1   c2   c3
# 1  yes  yes <NA>
# 2 <NA>   ok  yes
# 3   ok <NA>   ok
# 4  yes  yes <NA>
# 5 <NA>   ok  yes
# 6   ok <NA>   ok
# 7  yes  yes <NA>
# 8 <NA>   ok  yes
# 9   ok <NA>   ok
```

**toy data**

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("no", "ok", "yes"), class = "factor"), c2 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "ok", "yes"
), class = "factor"), c3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("no", "ok", "yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("c1", 
"c2", "c3"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Great answers above. I'll add that if not all of your columns are factors and/or you want to preserve all factor levels (including ones with no data) other than the one explicitly being removed you'll need a more general approach:

```
#Define a helper function
removeOneLevel <- function(v, badlevel){
  v[v==badlevel] = NA
  v2 = droplevels(v)
  levels(v2) = levels(v)[levels(v) != badlevel]
  return(v2)}

# Use dplyr to perform that function on all factor columns
library(dplyr)
dfNew = mutate_if(df, is.factor, removeOneLevel, badlevel = 'no')
```